# Is there any way to implement java entities like in grails domains

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

In Grails domains has methods like save, get, etc.
It means domains in Grails is spring beans?
Is there anyway to implement that functionality in spring java hibernate entities?
Has anyone implement similar approach ?

For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_users")
public class User {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    public String firstName;
}
```

and user this class like

```
user.save()
```

Comment: Why not just use hibernate?  Are you developing in grails, or just referencing it as an example?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [Active Record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) implementation for Java. I googled a bit and found these solutions:

1. [ActiveJDBC](https://www.baeldung.com/active-jdbc)
2. [ActiveJPA](https://www.infoq.com/articles/ActiveJPA/)
3. [ObjectiveSql](https://objsql.hashnode.dev/active-record-pattern-in-java)

I personally haven't used any of them, so I can't tell what are the pitfalls. Maybe if you make some research you'll find something that suites your purposes. But if we're talking about common practices, I've never seen any active record implementations in the production systems in my entire career, so they are probably not that popular (doesn't necessarily means they are bad).